# What is the idiomatic Groovy and Grails way of casting to a Domain Model class?

Tags: grails, groovy

Given the Grails Domain Classes "Apple.groovy" and "Orange.groovy", not strictly related, and the following Grails Service invoked from the Controllers:

```
package test

import grails.transaction.Transactional

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

@Transactional
class UploadService {

    def uploadApple(HttpServletRequest request, Apple o) {
        def file = request.getFile('payload')
        o.payload = file.getBytes()
        o.filename = file.originalFilename
        o.contentType = file.contentType
        o.save(flush:true)
    }

    def uploadOrange(HttpServletRequest request, Orange o) {
        def file = request.getFile('payload')
        o.payload = file.getBytes()
        o.filename = file.originalFilename
        o.contentType = file.contentType
        o.save(flush:true)
    }

}
```

How would one go about unifying this code under a common method? I was hoping Groovy's optional types would handle this for me, but I can't seem to be able invoke `.save()` successfully if I remove the types from the method signature.

Thanks in advance

Comment: aaik, save() is implemented as a metaclass extension. it doesn't matter if the type is declared or not in the method signature. what is the error you see ?

Comment: `Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/Apple/save
Class
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
Message
Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: UploadService.__execute([Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
Caused by
UploadService.__execute([Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;`

Comment: What is your `__execute()`?

Comment: Not sure how to check, it's whatever `grails create-service Upload` generates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid passing `request` to service and pass `File` to service. Did you try it this way?

```
def upload(file, obj) {
        obj.payload = file.getBytes()
        obj.filename = file.originalFilename
        obj.contentType = file.contentType
        obj.save(flush:true)
}
```

Unlike Java, Groovy does duck typing. Typing is concerned with assigning a type to any object. Duck typing is concerned with establishing the suitability of an object for some purpose.

Now you have to be careful because this will not work for every object. The reason that it works for `Apple` and `Orange` is because both have exactly the same set of attributes and attribute types.

One would wonder, why you would have two different domain that behave exactly the same, but that's obviously is a different discussion.

Comment: How would you invoke this from the Controller if you're not working with `File`s yet, but `HttpServletRequest`s?

Comment: You are getting the file from the request. So, in your controller you can call the service as such: `uploadService.upload(request.getFile('payload'), apple)` and for orange you pass `orange`, obviously. But before you pass the file to service, make sure it is not null or validate it.

Comment: Surprised it worked so well. It's not apparent to me why this would work and my initial approach wouldn't. Care to elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Grails 3, domain classes implement the [GormEntity](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/34feefddc98022d21d341fd144bc2216a62458ea/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormEntity.groovy) trait, which is where the `save()` method comes from. But that doesn't solve the issue with the `payload`, `filename`, and `contentType` properties.

What you can do is create an interface which declares the methods and properties common to both domain classes *and* also implements `org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity`. Then, have the domain classes implement the interface:

```
interface Uploadable extends GormEntity {
    byte [] payload
    String filename
    String contentType
}

class Apple implements Uploadable {
    byte [] payload
    String filename
    String contentType
}
```

Then, you can use the interface in your service.

```
@Transactional
class UploadService {

    def upload(HttpServletRequest request, Uploadable o) {
        def file = request.getFile('payload')
        o.payload = file.getBytes()
        o.filename = file.originalFilename
        o.contentType = file.contentType
        o.save(flush:true)
    }

}
```

Note: Since Grails injects the `GormEntity` trait into the domain classes automatically, I don't know what happens if you use it explicitly as shown.

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply; decided to accept another answer because it felt a bit more idiomatic, despite the fact that coming from a Java background yours make more sense to me.